# Bringing Data from SQL Server to AWS automatically

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis, ssis-2012

We have a requirement where we want to bring data present in SQL Server to AWS - SQL Server (i.e. AWS RDS).

At present the data is present in on-prem SQL Server and on 1st of every month, the data is then transferred from SQL server to excel sheet. The excel sheet contains 7 different tabs. Those tabs are then imported into AWS- SQL Server. Both the database are present on different server and different environment and the excel tabs are created manually by running stored procedure in the SQL Server (on-Prem)

Hence currently the process looks like:

**SQL Server (ON PREM) ---> Excel tabs --> SQL Server (AWS)**

My requirement is to transfer data from SQL Server (on prem) to SQL Server (AWS) so that we can eliminate Excel sheet step in between.

Can someone please suggest me how to automatically transfer the data?

Answer (score 1):

Just export the data to CSV files with bcp or something similiar on the source and import it with bulk insert or something similar on the destination

Comment: Bcp would have been useful if the exported was in the tables at SQL Server (on-prem) side, The data that is getting exported into excel is done using various SPs present on on-prem SQL Server

Comment: If you want to entirely remove the excel step in the loading process, I guess you will have to change the stored procedures generating the results. Then you can store the result in a table instead of excel, and use bcp out if you want to